# Unable to ping but I can see the arp in switch 4451

Tags: cisco, cisco-4500

Recently I got to know that I am unable to ping the IP addresses behind vlan236 from core1 whereas I am able to ping the same from core2 and able to ping the IP address of vlan236 from my laptop as well.

I can see the arp entry as well but no ping. Both core1 and core2 are in HSRP.

core1 is active , core2 is secondary and all the other vlan IP addresses are reachable from core 1 except this vlan 236

Can you pls advise?

config on Core1

```
sg624-fmr0-cs1-mn#sh run int vlan236
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 348 bytes
!
interface Vlan236
 description fab room 2 manufacturing network
 ip address 10.193.236.2 255.255.254.0
 no ip redirects
 no ip proxy-arp
 standby 236 ip 10.193.236.1
 standby 236 priority 210
 standby 236 preempt
 standby 236 name hsrp-vlan236
 logging event link-status
 end
```

arp details

```
sg624-fmr0-cs1-mn#sh ip arp | i Vlan236
Internet  10.193.236.1            -   0000.0c07.acec  ARPA   Vlan236
Internet  10.193.236.2            -   70e4.22c6.77bf  ARPA   Vlan236
Internet  10.193.236.5           63   0027.e3c2.647f  ARPA   Vlan236
Internet  10.193.236.9            9   000b.ab45.9ec2  ARPA   Vlan236
Internet  10.193.236.10           3   000b.ab45.baf2  ARPA   Vlan236
Internet  10.193.236.12           2   0cc4.7a46.3767  ARPA   Vlan236
Internet  10.193.236.13           0   0025.9023.1f8d  ARPA   Vlan236
Internet  10.193.236.16          63   0004.250e.83a2  ARPA   Vlan236
Internet  10.193.236.17           0   000b.abe0.27c9  ARPA   Vlan236
Internet  10.193.236.20           3   000b.ab45.f1b9  ARPA   Vlan236
Internet  10.193.236.32           2   0010.6f00.c51d  ARPA   Vlan236
Internet  10.193.236.33           8   0023.18c0.08d2  ARPA   Vlan236
Internet  10.193.236.35           0   0021.286d.1d88  ARPA   Vlan236
Internet  10.193.236.36           0   0021.283f.63ea  ARPA   Vlan236
!
sg624-fmr0-cs1-mn#ping 10.193.236.36
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.193.236.36, timeout is 2 seconds:
.....
Success rate is 0 percent (0/5)
```

config on core2

```
sg624-amr0-cs2-mn#sh run int vlan236
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 348 bytes
!
interface Vlan236
 description fab room 2 manufacturing network
 ip address 10.193.236.5 255.255.254.0
 no ip redirects
 no ip proxy-arp
 standby 236 ip 10.193.236.1
 standby 236 priority 190
 standby 236 preempt
 standby 236 name hsrp-vlan236
 logging event link-status
 end
!
sg624-amr0-cs2-mn#ping 10.193.236.36
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.193.236.36, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/3/8 ms
sg624-amr0-cs2-mn#
```

-Syed

Comment: What source is core1 using? What's the arp table on 36? (it could be sending it's reply to wrong MAC.)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the source address for ICMP echo - possibly it's set to something `10.193.236.36` cannot reply to.
2. Double check whether the MAC address `0021.283f.63ea` is correct for `10.193.236.36` (static ARP?).
3. Check whether `0021.283f.63ea` is actually in the switch's source-address/CAM table and whether the port is correct.
4. Check `10.193.236.36`'s local firewall for possible filtering (or switch ACLs).

Answer (score 0):

Check once windows firewall  status .and clear Mac address for that specific ip and please ensure ICMP is allowed in network. See there is no restriction on icmp